# Why don't gulp tasks created on a loop work as they should

Tags: gulp

I have this code

```
var tagfile = require('./_meta/tags.json');  
for(var i in tagfile.tags){  
    var taskName = tagfile.tags[i];  
    gulp.task(taskName, function() {  
        gulp.src('views/tags.jade')  
            .pipe(rename(taskName + ".html"))  
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/test/'));  
    })  
}
```

I have an object on file, and above I loop through the values and create gulp tasks. The tasks get created **but only one file is create (the last name in the object)**.

This is the object on file

```
{"tags":["one","three","four","two"]}
```

And only `two.html` get created. So the tasks are all created using `taskName` variable **but with the same variable** the filename is not what it should be

(I used `gulp-rename` and `gulp-concat` and the results are the same)

ps - the task is more complexed in actuality but in both cases the results are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var taskName` gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) outside of your `for` loop. That means the value of `taskName` is changed on every iteration of your `for` loop. When you finally come around to executing one of your tasks, the value of `taskName` will always be `two`, since that's the last value in your array.

You need to limit the scope of `taskName` to a closure to prevent this:

```
tagfile.tags.forEach(function(taskName) {
  gulp.task(taskName, function() {  
    gulp.src('views/tags.jade')  
      .pipe(rename(taskName + ".html"))  
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/test/'));  
  });  
});
```